# как сделать программу в си, чтобы когда вводишь целое плюсовое число от 1 до 8 на выходе было вот такое:

Tags: c

как сделать программу в си, чтобы когда вводишь целое плюсовое число от 1 до 8 на выходе было вот такое: (картинка ниже).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пусть введено N. Выводите с i-й строке N-i пробелов и i символов #. Просто, как табурет...

Comment: а как сделать центровку по правую сторону, и чтобы оно спрашивало пока я не введу от 1 до 8 , и игнорировало не целые и отрицательные числа?

Comment: "Дайте воды напиться, а то так есть хочется, что аж переночевать негде..."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    while (1) {
        int n;

        scanf("%d", &n);

        if (n < 1 || n > 8)
            continue;

        for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++)
                printf(" ");

            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
                printf("#");

            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: С проверками и с вводом значений

Comment: большое спасибо, я только начал учится.